# Laravel 5: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::exists()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement an Authorization Gate on the comments list on posts. I think I've managed to get it right because it works.

If the user is the owner of the comment, or is a moderator in the subreddit the comment is posted in, then he may edit it. If not, he won't be able to see the edit link (I'm using inline editing with X-Editable)

All works well until I submit a new comment, than I get the following error. But the comment get submitted to the database because I can see it on refresh.

> Undefined variable: isModerator on comment_list.blade.php

It's obvious that I need to pass `isModerator` variable to the view, so I did

```
$isModerator = $post->subreddit->moderators->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
```

This throws this error on page load, the entire post page crashes

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::exists()
>
> CommentController::view_data() in PostsController.php line 90

This is my `Gate` Authorization. Please note that `update-post` and `update-sub` work without a glitch.

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    parent::registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('update-comment', function($user, $comment, $isModerator) {
        if($user->id === $comment->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($isModerator) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    $gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post, $isModerator) {
        if ($user->id === $post->subreddit->user->id) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($user->id === $post->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($isModerator) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    $gate->define('update-sub', function($user, $subreddit) {
        if($user->id === $subreddit->user->id) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

The `view_data()` method in `CommentController`

```
public static function view_data(Request $request, Post $post) {
    $instance = new Self;
    $per_page = session('per_page')?session('per_page'):config('constants.per_page');
    $post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->with('comments')->where('id', $post->id)->first();
    $comment = $post->comments;
    $user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::id())->get();
    
    $isModerator = $post->subreddit->moderators->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
    
    $result['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $result['comments'] = $instance->comment_list($per_page, $request, $post, $comment, $user, $isModerator);
    $result['total_comments'] = $instance->total_comments($post);
    return $result;
}
```

The edit portion of the view looks like this

```
@can('update-comment', [$each_comment, $isModerator])
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="testedit" data-pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}" data-url="{{ url($each_comment->post_id . '/comment/update') }}">
            {!! $each_comment->comment !!}
        </a>
    </p>
@else
        <p>
            {!! $each_comment->comment !!}
        </p>
@endcan
```

And this is `show()` method in `PostsController`

```
public function show(Post $post, User $user, Request $request, Comment $comment)
{
    $post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->findOrFail($post->id);
    $ids = $post->subreddit;
    $isModerator = $ids->moderators()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists(); // this is line 90
    $modList = Moderator::where('subreddit_id', '=', $post->subreddit->id)->get();
    $view_data = CommentController::view_data($request, $post, $comment, $isModerator);

    return view('post/show', $view_data)->with('post', $post)
                            ->with('modList', $modList)
                            ->with('isModerator', $isModerator);
}
```

**Relations**

`Comment` Model

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function commentvotes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote');
}
```

`Post` Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
}

public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}

public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moderator');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

`Subreddit` Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moderator');
}
```

`Moderator` Model

```
public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Comment: please post your relations

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: Change line 90 temporarily to `$isModerator = $ids->moderators()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()` and run `dd($moderators)` to see if it actually returns something.

Comment: Sorry, `dd($isModerator)`, not `dd($moderators)`. Durrr

Comment: @TimLewis It returns a `HasMany` collection like this http://pastebin.com/85NHE4hb - However, if I re-add `exists()` it will return true or false. And this is in `PostsController` and not `CommentController`

Comment: That's what it returns with `->first()` closure?

Comment: Ah no, with `first()` it returns null.

Comment: @TimLewis it returns null in the subreddit I am not a moderator in, but if I goto a post in a subreddit that I am a moderator in, it returns a `Moderator` collection like this http://pastebin.com/SgNg1z7k

Comment: That makes more sense. Now looking over the Laravel 5.1 API, I don't actually see any documentation on the `->exists()` function. That being said, I'll post a quick alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know the usage of `->exists()`, but the basic premise is simply checking if the current user is a `Moderator` of a specific `Subreddit`, you can simply do the following:

```
$check = $ids->moderators()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
$isModerator = $check != NULL ? true : false;
// If $check doesn't return NULL (ie returns a Moderator object) then you are a moderator.
```

Comment: I am still getting `Undefined variable: isModerator in comment_list.blade.php` which is this line `@can('update-comment', [$each_comment, $isModerator])`

Comment: Quick thing to try: `->with(['modList' => $modList, 'isModerator' => $isModerator])` instead of chaining `->with()`s. Also what is `@can`? I don't see that in the documentation either...

Comment: I think that did it, I passed `$isModerator`  as a variable in `post_this_comment()` method as well. It all seems to click now.

Comment: You don't have to use a ternary when you just want to assign true or false, just doing `$isModerator = $check != NULL;` should be enough. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you're ever in doubt about what a function does, check this page out too: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/. If you type something like `Model` or `Eloquent` in the searchbar, it'll show a detailed list of all the available classes, methods, functions, etc. And @JoelHinz yes, that's true :P Simplicity over readability lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you `$isModerator = $ids->moderators()->where('user_id', Auth::id())` return NULL instead of collection object.So you can't use `->exists()` method.
Did you try to use whereHas \ has methods instead of `->where('user_id', Auth::id())`?

Comment: This also gives `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereHas()`